# Pandas drop rows in one dataframe that share a common value with a rows in a column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

I have a data frame called x1:

```
 FID  g1    g2    g3
  0   19    20    13
  1   16    11    14
  2   15    20    11
```

and a data frame called x2:

```
 FID  g1   
  1   16
```

I want to alter x1 so that it does not include the row in x2:

```
 FID  g1    g2    g3
  0   19    20    13
  2   15    20    11
```

I've tried:

```
x1 = pd.concat([x1,x2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

but think this only works if the data frames have matching schemas. Can I just keep rows in x1 that don't share the FID values in x2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.isin` to create a boolean series of the values in the `FID` column of `x1` that appear in the `FID` column of `x2`.

Then simply use `pd.DataFrame.loc` with the operator `~` to invert the boolean series and select the rows of `x1` whose values in the `FID` column *don't* appear in the `FID` column of `x2`:

```
cond = x1.FID.isin(x2.FID)
x1.loc[~cond] 
# output:
   FID  g1  g2  g3
0    0  19  20  13
2    2  15  20  11
```

Comment: This works! However it only considers FID. Does the value of g1 matter?

Comment: @ Bjorn no, I only want it to consider FID. In that case, shouldn't it be: cond = x1.FID.isin(x2.FID)  ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question (I thought FID was the DataFrame's index). But yes it's the same logic. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
x1.drop(x2['FID'])
```

## output

```
    FID  g1  g2  g3
 0    0  19  20  13
 2    2  15  20  11
```